# Countdown timer with php session

Tags: php, session, timer, countdowntimer

I need your help with creating countdown timer with php session.I will use and show this timer result on some pages.Has anyone created such thing or has some useful tutorial.I have searched many but havent find the thing that I need.

Please help me!

Comment: PHP runs on the server. If you want a countdown, you need to do it on the client in Javascript.

Comment: But if I will do it with Javascript how i can use the countdown result on many pages?If you have any ideas please tell me.

Comment: Use a cookie or localStorage to keep track of the timer.

Comment: Can you give me some example dear Barmar?

Answer (score 2):

This could help you:

(It's a example page)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Datum-Countdown mit JavaScript</title>

    <script language="JavaScript">
      //Goal
      var jahr=2222, monat=2, tag=22, stunde=22, minute=22, sekunde=22;
      var zielDatum=new Date(jahr,monat-1,tag,stunde,minute,sekunde);

      function countdown() {
        startDatum=new Date(); //Date now

        // Ccalculate Coutdown
        if(startDatum<zielDatum)  {

          var jahre=0, monate=0, tage=0, stunden=0, minuten=0, sekunden=0;

          // Years
          while(startDatum<zielDatum) {
            jahre++;
            startDatum.setFullYear(startDatum.getFullYear()+1);
          }
          startDatum.setFullYear(startDatum.getFullYear()-1);
          jahre--;

          // months
          while(startDatum<zielDatum) {
            monate++;
            startDatum.setMonth(startDatum.getMonth()+1);
          }
          startDatum.setMonth(startDatum.getMonth()-1);
          monate--;

          // days
          while(startDatum.getTime()+(24*60*60*1000)<zielDatum) {
            tage++;
            startDatum.setTime(startDatum.getTime()+(24*60*60*1000));
          }

          // hours
          stunden=Math.floor((zielDatum-startDatum)/(60*60*1000));
          startDatum.setTime(startDatum.getTime()+stunden*60*60*1000);

          // minutes
          minuten=Math.floor((zielDatum-startDatum)/(60*1000));
          startDatum.setTime(startDatum.getTime()+minuten*60*1000);

          // seconds
          sekunden=Math.floor((zielDatum-startDatum)/1000);

          // format
          (jahre!=1)?jahre=jahre+" Jahre,  ":jahre=jahre+" Jahr,  ";
          (monate!=1)?monate=monate+" Monate,  ":monate=monate+" Monat,  ";
          (tage!=1)?tage=tage+" Tage,  ":tage=tage+" Tag,  ";
          (stunden!=1)?stunden=stunden+" Stunden,  ":stunden=stunden+" Stunde,  ";
          (minuten!=1)?minuten=minuten+" Minuten  und  ":minuten=minuten+" Minute  und  ";
          if(sekunden<10) sekunden="0"+sekunden;
          (sekunden!=1)?sekunden=sekunden+" Sekunden":sekunden=sekunden+" Sekunde";

          document.countdownform.countdowninput.value=
              jahre+monate+tage+stunden+minuten+sekunden;

          setTimeout('countdown()',200);
        }

        else document.countdownform.countdowninput.value=
            "0 Jahre,  0 Monate,  0 Tage,  0 Stunden,  0 Minuten  und  00 Sekunden";
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="countdown()">
    <form name="countdownform">
      <p>
        <input size="75" name="countdowninput">
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have tested it but there is empty input.How I can use it?

Comment: @AnahitGhazaryan it should just work fine! You have to have javascript enabled

Comment: @AnahitGhazaryan which OS and browser do you use?

Comment: It is enabled but in input is empty result.Can you help me with creating a countdown timer with php session?

Comment: Chrome I use and in the settings javascript is enabled

Comment: @AnahitGhazaryan your file is saved in the webserver ? and your calling the file over the webserver? (which version?)

Comment: @AnahitGhazaryan Simple make: 1. a file in the webserver folder 2. copy the entire code! and load the page! It must work!

Comment: I have already done it but I see empty input.Did you have any ideas?

Comment: @AnahitGhazaryan hmm try to change this: `<input size="75" type="text" name="countdowninput">` also what version are you using?

Comment: No the same I got empty input and I am using that latest version of js

Comment: What is the result in your side?

Comment: @AnahitGhazaryan it should be this : `207 years,  3 months,  14 days,  4 hours,  27 minutes  52 seconds`

Comment: hmm dont know why it was not working properly.Did you know how to such thing with php session and I only need minutes timer dont need year and month

Comment: Oh your code is working...!I have left one line...Just one question how can I use the result of this timer on other pages?I have multistep contact form and must use this result on each step.Did you have any idea?

Comment: @AnahitGhazaryan don't know, you almost have to have a timer server side! But i think you can work now with the timer!

Answer (score 0):

This is another easy way to do this

```
<?php
   session_start();

   //to reset the saved countdown
   if (!empty($_REQUEST['resetCountdown']))
   {
       unset($_SESSION['startTime']);
   }

   if (empty($_SESSION['startTime']))
   {
       $_SESSION['startTime'] = time();
   }

   //In seconds
   $startTime = time() - $_SESSION['startTime'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var countdown = 60; //in seconds
    var startTime = <?php echo $startTime; ?>;

    startCountdown(startTime, countdown);

    function startCountdown(startFrom, duration)
    {
        //countdown implementation
    }
 </script>
 <?php echo $startTime; ?>
```